# Creating a mongodb capped collection in java

Tags: mongodb-java

I want to create a capped collection from Java code. I found the syntax for creating it through JavaScript, but could not find an example for Java.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("127.0.0.1");
DB db = mongo.getDB("mydbid");

DBCollection collection;
if (db.collectionExists("mycollection")) {
        collection = db.getCollection("mycollection");
    } else {
        collection = /* ????? Create the collection ?????? */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the DB.createCollection operation and then specify a DBObject that has **capped** as a parameter. You can then specify **size** and **max** in order to control the  byte size and the maximum number of documents. The MongoDB site has a [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) on capped collections that explains all the options, but is missing an example for each driver.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("127.0.0.1");
DB db = mongo.getDB("mydbid");

DBCollection collection;
if (db.collectionExists("mycollection")) {
        collection = db.getCollection("mycollection");
    } else {
        DBObject options = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("capped", true).add("size", 2000000000l).get();
        collection = db.createCollection("mycollection", options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am wondering is there any other approach other than using if else for this problem?

Comment: The if/else is only so you can do a dynamic creation if the collection doesn't exist. If the capped collection is created prior to its usage then you only need the **else** portion of the code example.

Answer (score 0):

With more recent java mongo driver (ie 3.4) the creation should slightly change:

```
CreateCollectionOptions opts = new CreateCollectionOptions().capped(true).sizeInBytes(1024*1024);
database.createCollection("test", opts);
```

Please, notice that the `createCollection` is not returning any value.