# Creating a mongodb capped collection using c# api

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the C# MongoDB driver, we currently create our collection like so:

```
MongoServer mongoServer = MongoServer.Create("some conn str");
MongoDatabase db = mongoServer.GetDatabase("mydb");
MongoCollection logs = db.GetCollection("mycoll");
```

I would like to use `mycoll` as a capped collection. I haven't seen any examples or documentation specifics on how to create a capped collection using the C# driver. I've found tons of JS examples, and even a Java example (here: [Creating a mongodb capped collection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229237/creating-a-mogodb-capped-collection-in-java)).

Has anyone had to do this before, or know if it's possible in C#?

Comment: A lot has happened in the world of MongoDb since Jul 3 12 at 18:35.  The accepted answer is not longer the best one, nor is the one with the highest votes. @i3arnon answer is (at the time of writing) the best answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating a collection, you need to specify that the collection should be capped by using `CollectionOptions`:

```
CollectionOptionsBuilder options = CollectionOptions.SetCapped(true);
database.CreateCollection("mycoll", options);
```

You need to create the collection explicitly (by calling `CreateCollection` method) to be able to provide your options. When calling `GetCollection` with non-existing collection, it gets implicitly created with default options.

Comment: This is now deprecated, please see @i3arnon's answer

Answer (score 17):

Starting from v2.0 of the driver there's a new `async`-only API. The old API should no longer be used as it's a blocking facade over the new API and is deprecated.

The currently recommended way to create a capped collection is by calling and awaiting `IMongoDatabase.CreateCollectionAsync` with a `CreateCollectionOptions` instance that specifies `Capped = true` and `MaxSize = <cap size in bytes>` or `MaxDocuments = <cap in doc count>` (or both).

```
async Task CreateCappedCollectionAsync()
{
    var database = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("HamsterSchool");
    await database.CreateCollectionAsync("Hamsters", new CreateCollectionOptions
    {
        Capped = true,
        MaxSize = 1024,
        MaxDocuments = 10,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is another example; don't forget to set the MaxSize and MaxDocuments property.

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/");
var db = server.GetDatabase("PlayGround");

var options = CollectionOptions
   .SetCapped(true)
   .SetMaxSize(5000)
   .SetMaxDocuments(100);

if (!db.CollectionExists("Log"))
    db.CreateCollection("Log", options);
```

Comment: Yep, very similar to how I ended up doing it. +1 for extended details. Thanks!